# Не могу подключиться к базе данных в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, intellij-idea

Подчёркивает строчку Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"). Я понятия не имею в чём может быть проблема. Пересмотрел кучу статей и видео. Везде предлагают вручную добавить файл (mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar) в библиотеки проекта, хотя Maven уже за меня всё вроде как добавил. Кароче пробовал добавить вручную, но и это не помогло. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: Скрин кода][image: Project Structure]

---

jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC.

Comment: Кстати, в новых версиях драйверов jdbc 4.0+ ,если не ошибаюсь , не нужно делать Class.forName().

Answer (score 2):

Class#forName выбрасывает исключение ClassNotFoundException. Обработайте его правильно

Comment: Блин, точно.. исправил. осталось от закомментированных строчек.  но это всё равно не помогло. пишет Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. и т.д. ......

Comment: @Владислав Новиков, ну так прочитайте внимательно ошибку и, может быть, поймете чего от Вас хотят

Comment: Прочитал и заменил, но опять же это не сильно помогло.